# Como fazer um getter da minha response request no flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Tenho uma função que realiza login e preciso guardar o token no `storage`:

```
  login() async {

    setState(() { isLoading = true; });
     
    final response = await http.post('https://xxx.net/api/login', 
    body: {
      "email": emailController.text,
      "senha": senhaController.text,
    });

    if (response.statusCode == 202) {
      Toast.show("Login ok", context, duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity:  Toast.CENTER);
      // Write value 
      await storage.write(key: 'token', value: response.body.token);
    } else {
      Toast.show("Email ou senha incorreto", context, duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity:  Toast.CENTER);
    }

    setState(() { isLoading = false; });
  }
```

Porém, estou recebendo:

> The getter 'token' isn't defined for the class 'String'.
> Try importing the library that defines 'token', correcting the name to the
> name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'token'

Como posso fazer um getter para meu response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `response` que você obtém da requisição não possui o atributo `token` que está tentando acessar. Nesse caso o que deve ser feito é converter o `body` e obter assim um `map` com os valores que sua `API` enviar (o seu `token` vem nesse objeto).

Obs: Não esquecer de importar o `dart.convert` para o arquivo.

#### Exemplo

```dart
 login() async {

 setState(() { isLoading = true; });

 final response = await http.post('https://xxx.net/api/login', 
 body: {
   "email": emailController.text,
   "senha": senhaController.text,
 });

 if (response.statusCode == 202) {
   Toast.show("Login ok", context, duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity:  Toast.CENTER);
   // Write value

   //==== ADD ====
   var mapResponse = json.decode(response.body);
   var token = mapResponse["token"];
   //=============

   await storage.write(key: 'token', value: token);
 } else {
   Toast.show("Email ou senha incorreto", context, duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG, gravity:  Toast.CENTER);
 }

 setState(() { isLoading = false; });
}
```